# How to move imageView outside display?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to show some images (3 or 5 or 7 etc) in such a way that middle image is on center screen and the rest spread out to the sides, something like this:

```
    +-------------+
[i] | [i] [i] [i] | [i]
    +-------------+
```

I write:

```
    for(int i=0;i<(numOfPages-1);i++){
        ShadowedImageView image = new ShadowedImageView(this);
        pagesArray[i] = image;
        pagesArray[i].setId((i+1));
    }

    int firstPage = currentPage-((int) (numPagesToLoad/2));
    int lastPage = (currentPage+((int) (numPagesToLoad/2)))+1;

    for(int i=firstPage;i<lastPage;i++){
        pagesArray[i].scale = 11;
        pagesArray[i].download(someUrlToLoadImage);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.leftMargin = -20; // this not work !
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, (firstPage+i));
        layout.addView(pagesArray[i],params);
    }
```

I have custom ImageView class and i put them in RelativeLayout.

Comment: Images do not hiding, do not set centrally

Comment: The problem is that I do not want this. I want to show always the same ammount of conteners and replace images moving them from one contener to another

Answer (score 1):

try to use Gallery

The sample is here http://www.androidpeople.com/android-gallery-example

Hope, it help you!

Answer (score 0):

You can declare One relativelayout in your activity and use the following

```
ImageView image = findViewById(R.id.image);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = 
    (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)image.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, 0);
image.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```